# Why is android SQLite Cursor at position -1 even after calls like moveToNext()?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

This code used to be working, but now when I get to the Cursor.get methods in the for loop, I get:

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5

The Cursor.getCount() methods is bigger then zero, but still, the cursor doesn't move.

I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper.
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Profile> GetAllProfiles() throws SQLiteException{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] selection = {COL_ID, COL_NAME, COL_IMAGE};
    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_PLAYERS, selection, null, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

    int colIndexID = c.getColumnIndex(COL_ID);
    int colIndexName = c.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME);
    int colIndexImage = c.getColumnIndex(COL_IMAGE);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        profiles.add(new Profile(
        c.getInt(colIndexID),
        c.getString(colIndexName),
        c.getBlob(colIndexImage)));
    }

    database.close();
    return profiles;
}
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Did you change any column names or added any new columns in the table after you first ran the app?

Comment: An image blob column hints that you might have too large rows in the database, and the move fails. Android CursorWindows are restricted to 2MB.